# PHP : Detect Content-Type of the page

Tags: php

In PHP, we can set the Content-Type by :

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

But if I work on a PHP class that requires to show an error message, which the format of the error message is shown according to the content type, e.g. if the page is `text/html`, it shows HTML-formatted error message; else, show plain text error message.

Is there any function / snippet that I can use to detect the page Content-Type ?

Note: Given that the PHP class file is "attached" to the page by `require_once()`

**UPDATE:** From @Tamil's answer, I performed a short test:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
echo finfo_file($finfo, __FILE__) . "\n";
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

It returns `text/x-php` only. But I expect the result will return `text/plain` .

Comment: `PHP class is attached to the page` Whaaat??!. Ok, if you determine which mime type the page should be, why can't you just check it?

Comment: I mean the PHP class file is attached to the page. How to check ? You mean by `mime_content_type()` ? How to apply it to a PHP class that detects the file attaching to ?

Comment: use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [`headers_list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) function:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$headers = headers_list();

var_dump($headers);
?>
```

Shows (in my case):

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.5"
  [1]=>
  string(24) "Content-Type: text/plain"
}
```

---

To normalize result array you may use this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$headers = headers_list();

foreach($headers as $index => $value) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(': ', $value);

    unset($headers[$index]);

    $headers[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($headers);
?>
```

Shows:

```
array(2) {
  ["X-Powered-By"]=>
  string(9) "PHP/5.4.5"
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(10) "text/plain"
}
```

So, the `Content-Type` header with normalized array might be obtained like this:

```
echo $headers['Content-Type'];
```

Comment: Nice ! Sadly I have to iterate the array to find the `Content-Type`.

Comment: *sidenote:* if I don't set the `Content-Type` via `header()`, the array does not contain `Content-Type` information.